# Class 'Role" not found [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]

Tags: php, laravel-5

So I've seen a lot of similar questions asked about class not found errors but unless I'm totally missing somethings obvious, I just can't understand how the following method call does not see my role class and results in the class not found exception:

```
 $user->makeEmployee("admin")
```

Here is my user class with makeEmployee():

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];


/**
 * Get the roles a user has
 */
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'users_roles');
}

/**
 * Find out if User is an employee, based on if has any roles
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isEmployee()
{
    $roles = $this->roles->toArray();
    return !empty($roles);
}

/**
 * Find out if user has a specific role
 *
 * $return boolean
 */
public function hasRole($check)
{
    return in_array($check, array_fetch($this->roles->toArray(), 'name'));
}

/**
 * Get key in array with corresponding value
 *
 * @return int
 */
private function getIdInArray($array, $term)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $term) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    throw new UnexpectedValueException;
}

/**
 * Add roles to user to make them a concierge
 */
public function makeEmployee($title)
{
    $assigned_roles = array();

    $roles = array_fetch(Role::all()->toArray(), 'name');

    switch ($title) {
        case 'admin':
            $assigned_roles[] = $this->getIdInArray($roles, 'create_message');
        /*case 'member':
            $assigned_roles[] = $this->getIdInArray($roles, 'create_customer');
        case 'concierge':
            $assigned_roles[] = $this->getIdInArray($roles, 'add_points');
            $assigned_roles[] = $this->getIdInArray($roles, 'redeem_points');*/
            break;
        default:
            throw new \Exception("The employee status entered does not exist");
    }

    $this->roles()->attach($assigned_roles);
}
}
```

And here is my Role class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'roles';
    /**
     * Set timestamps off
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * Get users with a certain role
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_roles');
    }
}
```

If they are both is the same namespace can't I just use `Role` in `User`?
I've also tried clear-compile and composer dump-auto as well as replacing the `Role` reference with `App\Role` and including `use App\Role` at the top. I'm using PHPStorm and it catches the reference fine as well as I am able to jump to the `Role` class definition from the user code. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Sorry I made a typo I already used dump-autoload and it did not help. But I did find out that dump-auto is also a command. What's the difference between the two? Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: So I'm rolling back my migrations. Using dump-autoload and adding my migrations again. The last migration creates a new admin user and makes a call to the user function in question which is where the I run into problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be doing

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'users_roles');
```

and dump-auto and dump-autoload both are same.

Comment: Thanks so much this was it! I missed that completely. I'm still wrapping my head around models.

Answer (score 2):

You don't pass a class, `Role` is a string argument for a method that gets called in the class you are extending, so you will need to provide the class together with its full namespace.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'users_roles');
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean replace 'Role' with '\Apps\Role'?

Comment: Thanks  for your help as well. I'm not sure who answered first... so I don't know who to give the credit to.